# Can Lady Comp predict women's fertility cycles with 99.3% accuracy?

Tags: medical-science, contraception, menstrual-cycle

I just came across a seemingly amazing product, called Pearly or Lady Comp. This product was recently mentioned in Sweden's biggest newspaper.

According to the company, it can predict female fertility at the rate of 99.3% based on the menstruation cycle. This is higher than the preventive effect of birth-control.

The product: [Lady Comp](http://www.raxmedical.com/ladycomp.php)

> Lady Comp is programmed with all available natural family planning research data and uses biomathematical forecasting calculations as well as the very latest computer techniques. LadyComp contains the first medical expertise to help provide safe, reliable and natural birth control.

The studies they reference: [Clinical Studies](http://www.raxmedical.com/clinical-studies.php)

Are their claims true?

Comment: It seems slightly odd that there are no quoted studies since 1998 and some of the studies were not published.

Comment: I suspect the numbers here are apples to oranges.  It is hard to compare the introduction of a catalyst(semen) to the start of a reaction, versus withholding the catalyst.  It is going to be much more effective to with hold than to inhibit the process.  Especially with a process that is not terribly efficient in achieving reaction under normal conditions versus the perfect conditions the lab tests of birth control.

Comment: Chad: Thanks for the comment. As I understand the studies, what has been done is to compare sexually active women that are using the LadyComp to know what days they should avoid sex and conventional birthcontrol, and see how many get pregnant anyways. To me, these metrics seem comparable, are they not?

Comment: Is that 99.3% accuracy per measurement? Because that would mean that with 100 measurements you'd have 50.47% chance of at least one failure.

Comment: I remember reading that some psychological effect can cause spontaneous ovulation in a women. (Can't find where) This would invalidate any predictability. Also irregular cycle exists and mess with such a thing.

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges when you take the number and compare it directly with the numbers for birth control. The birth control numbers are about actual usage that contain human errors. Those numbers don't seem to include human usage errors.

Comment: I would rather look at the typical use numbers, than the perfect use numbers. "after about one year of exposure, the probability of unintended pregnancy was 5.3%". https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28098936

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if the woman has reliable cycles and also pays attention to her cervical fluid.

When a woman ovulates, it intrinsically causes a rise in progesterone (this is known as the luteal phase). The presence of progesterone causes the body's basal temperature to rise by a few centigrade. Therefore, a slight raise in the BBT mid-cycle helps to confirm the beginning of the luteal phase, ie. ovulation. This 'temperature shift' pattern becomes predictable if the woman has consistent, normal cycles and so charting one's BBT (which is what the Lady Comp does for you) will give you a good idea of when to avoid sexual intercourse due to the foreseen ovulation. According to one study (1):

> **Basal temperature is an indirect measure of ovulation as a result of
>   the progesterone-induced temperature increase** of ∼0.3 °C from the
>   follicular phase, when progesterone is low, to the luteal phase, when
>   progesterone peaks following ovulation [7]. [...]∼75% of cycles had a
>   temperature rise within 3 days of the LH surge [21].

I did not see anywhere on the Lady comp site, however, that cervical mucus is also documented. Lady Comp takes into account the cycle length and basal body temperature (BBT), which is quite similar to the natural family planning method of the book Taking Back your Fertility by Toni Weschler (http://www.tcoyf.com/), except the latter also observes and documents cervical fluid changes (also known as cervical mucus). To have such a high success rate in preventing pregnancy as Lady comp claims, cervical mucus must also be accounted for because different phases of the menstrual cycle correlate to different phases of cervical mucus, and this factor determines whether or not the sperm can travel up the female reproductive tract to actually reach the ovulated egg. In a study done on bovine to determine fertility properties of this mucus in mammals (2):

> Cervical mucus becomes more plentiful, watery, less viscous and **easier
>   to traverse by spermatozoa** in the follicular phase of the ovarian
>   cycle, as well as under oestrogen administration. On the contrary, in
>   the luteal phase of the cycle or under progesterone administration,
>   this mucus becomes scanty, opalescent, viscous and, consequently, not
>   favourable to sperm passage. Similarly, oviductal mucus becomes
>   progressively less viscous during a short period after ovulation
>   (Hunter 1995).
>
> A close relationship between the rheological behaviour of bovine
>   vaginal ﬂuid obtained at oestrus and the molecular organization of its
>   structural elements has been shown. During the course of oestrus,
>   cervical mucus is able to achieve a dramatic reduction in its
>   **mechanical barrier eﬀect** while maintaining its three-dimensional
>   ﬁlamentous structure. This structure is related to a low consistency
>   index of samples, favouring sperm migration eﬃciency to the utmost.
>   Taken together, all these ﬁndings suggest that in mid-oestrus (...),
>   there seems only to be a short 2–4 h period (...) available for the
>   sperm to reach the uterus. Either side of this time interval, **the
>   mucus is mechanically more hostile for the movement of sperm**.

<sub>(1) Bedford J.L., Prior J.C., Hitchcock C.L., Barr S.I. Detecting evidence of luteal activity by least-squares quantitative basal temperature analysis against urinary progesterone metabolites and the effect of wake-time variability  (2009) European Journal of Obstetrics Gynecology and Reproductive Biology, 146 (1) , pp. 76-80.</sub>

<sub>(2)Rutllant J, López-Béjar M, López-Gatius F. Ultrastructural and Rheological Properties of Bovine Vaginal Fluid and its Relation to Sperm Motility and Fertilization: a Review. Reproduction In Domestic Animals [serial online]. April 2005;40(2):79-86. Available from: Academic Search Premier, Ipswich, MA. Accessed January 4, 2013.</sub>

Comment: I am afraid this does not answer the question about Lady Comp at all. Lady Comp does not take cervical mucus into account. Its only input is menstruation and body temperature. Studies about sympto-thermal methods are therefore not relevant for it.